# UserFriendlyException for Automapper profile

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I faced into issue. I have business rule which defined in Entity, while validate this rule in entity I throw UserFriendlyException in case of  business rule was broken. Example:

```cs
private DateTime? _expireDate;

public DateTime? ExpireDate {
    get => _expireDate;
    set {
        if (value.HasValue) {
            _expireDate = EnsureExpireDateRules (value.Value);
            PeriodInMonth = 0;
        }
    }
}

private DateTime EnsureExpireDateRules (DateTime dateTime) {
    dateTime = dateTime.GetDateZeroTime ();

    var currentUtcDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow.GetDateZeroTime ();

    if (dateTime <= currentUtcDateTime)
        throw new UserFriendlyException ("License date should be at least one day late than today.");

    return dateTime;
}
```

And in Automapper profile, I have basically default rule

CreateMap();

And when it happen , i don't have UserFriendlyException on client side, instead of it I've got ordinary exception with 500 code(Internal Server Error).
In log system I see following:

```
AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Error mapping types.

Mapping types:
LicenseRequestInput -> LicenseRequest
LicenseManager.LicenseManager.Dto.LicenseRequestInput -> LicenseManager.LicenseManager.Entities.LicenseRequest

Type Map configuration:
LicenseRequestInput -> LicenseRequest
LicenseManager.LicenseManager.Dto.LicenseRequestInput -> LicenseManager.LicenseManager.Entities.LicenseRequest

Destination Member:
ExpireDate
 ---> Abp.UI.UserFriendlyException: License date should be at least one day late than today.
   at LicenseManager.LicenseManager.Entities.LicenseRequest.EnsureExpireDateRules(DateTime dateTime) in /Users/grinay/License management portal/src/LicenseManager.Core/LicenseManager/Entities/LicenseRequest.cs:line 56
.....more......
```

Looks like ABP doesn't intercept exception which comes from Automap profile. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: how about having your business rules somewhere else besides inside the automapper?  personally I'd find that a little obscure  - but that's just my opinion

Comment: Business rule inside the entity. Not in automapper itself. Entity exactly the place where business rule should be.

Comment: ah - i see - my mistake

Comment: Can you share the code which your call AutoMapper MapTo on LicenseRequestInput?

Answer (score 0):

**The Problem:**

Auto mapper wraps the `UserFriendlyException` with `AutoMapperMappingException`. Because the outer exception is not `UserFriendlyException` anymore, ABP cannot handle it!

**The solution:**

Put `EnsureExpireDateRules()` inside your DTO (`LicenseRequestInput`) and everything will work fine.

**Update:**

The best practice for what you wanna do is;

Make all your properties `protected set`, make constructor protected. You can create a public method to initialize your entity with mandatory properties. And let your manager handle your business domain logic.

```
public class MyEntity 
{
    public DateTime? ExpireDate {get; protected set;}

    protected MyEntity()
    {

    }

    public MyEntity(mandatoryPropertiesToCreateYourEntity...)
    {

    }
}
```

---

```
 public class MyEntityManager
    {

        public void SetExpireDate(MyEntity myEntity, DateTime? expireDate){
        {
              if(myBusinessLogicIsOk) {
                  myEntity.ExpireDate = expireDate;
              }
              else
              {
                  throw new Exception("Invalid expire date!");
              }
        }
   }
```

Comment: Unfortunately it violate architecture style.

Comment: I've updated my answer and added the best practice for your case.

Answer (score 0):

I extend AbpExceptionFilter for this. Not sure if it good practice, but I've already using it anyway to wrap Task return values.

So what I did is to unwrap UserFriendlyException.

I've inherit AbpExceptionFilter and override HandleAndWrapException method.

```cs
protected override void HandleAndWrapException(ExceptionContext context, WrapResultAttribute wrapResultAttribute)
        {
  if (!ActionResultHelper.IsObjectResult(context.ActionDescriptor.GetMethodInfo().ReturnType))
            {
                return;
            }

            context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = GetStatusCode(context, wrapResultAttribute.WrapOnError);

            if (!wrapResultAttribute.WrapOnError)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (context.Exception is AutoMapperMappingException && context.Exception.InnerException is UserFriendlyException)
            {
                context.Exception = context.Exception.InnerException;;
            }

            context.Result = new ObjectResult(
                new AjaxResponse(
                    _errorInfoBuilder.BuildForException(context.Exception),
                    context.Exception is AbpAuthorizationException
                )
            );

            EventBus.Trigger(this, new AbpHandledExceptionData(context.Exception));

            context.Exception = null; //Handled!

        }
```

and replace default filter with my

```cs
 public override void PreInitialize()
        {
...
            Configuration.ReplaceService<AbpExceptionFilter, CustomAbpExceptionFilter>();

...
        }
```

Now it return me my UserFriendlyException in case of mapping error.